# How to display two digit number instead of one Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, number-formatting

**Hi** I want to display all one digit numbers (from 0 to 9) in two digits in twig ( like 00 01 02 .... 09 ) the rest will remain in two digits (from 10 to 99) is it possible to do that ?

Comment: `{{ "%02d"|format(my.number) }}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
{{ "%02d"|format(my.number) }}
```

As per @MarkBaker's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363985/how-to-display-two-digit-number-instead-of-one-twig/29364564#comment46911310_29363985).